# Detect type of object in ArrayList

Tags: java

I'm attempting to make a class that will convert ArrayLists of objects into ArrayLists of other objects. i.e.

```
ArrayList<Foo> convert(ArrayList<Bar> input){
     //conversion logic
}

ArrayList<Bar> convert(ArrayList<Foo> input){
     //conversion logic
}
```

Unfortunately Java doesn't want to have two functions with the same name and what it believes to be the same inputs and outputs.

I'm attempting to go a different route.  Instead of multiple functions with the same name, I want to make one function that accepts an ArrayList, determines which type of object is inside, does the proper conversion, and returns an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList convert(ArrayList input){
     //conversion logic for Foo

     //conversion logic for Bar
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Is there any subtype relationship between Bar and Foo for your purposes?

Comment: Side issue: For flexibility the input should be an interface, such as List or even better Collection. Actually the return type should also be an interface.

Comment: Could you please clarify your goal? Do you want to create a generic converter or conversion between few types? In the latter case, you could just include the source or target type name in the method name.

Comment: I'm using GWT and google app engine, since GWT doesn't play nicely with GAE I need to have two copies of my entities: One for GWT (just pojo), one for GAE (with annotations).  My end goal is to make converting the objects as easy as possible, since there will be A LOT of converting back and forth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about an interface:

```
public class Converter<From, To> {
    List<To> convert(List<From> input);
}
```

And then have as many implementations as you want. For example:

```
private static final Converter<Foo, Bar> fooToBarConverter = new Converter<Foo, Bar>() {
    public List<Bar> convert(List<Foo> input) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
public <T, U> ArrayList<U> convert(Class<T> typeIn, ArrayList<T> input){     
    // dispatch on typeIn
}
```

Or better yet

```
public <T, U, V extends ArrayList<U>> V convert(Class<T> typeIn, 
Class<V> typeOut, ArrayList<T> input){     
    // dispatch on typeIn
    return typeOut.cast(yourConversionResult);
}
```

Because you might return `ArrayList<Foo>` or `ArrayList<Bar>` within the same method and having the proper cast will help you return them without compiler warnings.

**Edit:** The return type cast for the second sample wasn't going to work. Tried to fix it

Comment: I'm thinking this might be better than my answer. (By the way, you can add a "public" in there to get the syntax highlighting off of XML mode).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the <T, U> syntax.  Could you provide a more verbose example, or perhaps a link?

Comment: @KevMo: It means the method is generic, even though the containing class might not be.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure about the return type cast though.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically describing a "map" in terms of functional programming.  Take a list of objects, apply some operation to each object and accumulate the results in another list.  There are libraries out there that implement this stuff already, although i haven't looked recently.  I know commons collections has this for pre-generics collections.

the gist of the solution is (similar to mmeyers solution):

```
public interface Function<From,To> {
  public To apply(From);
}

public <From,To> List<To> map(List<From> fromList, Function<From,To> fun)  {
  // call fun.apply() on every element in fromList and return a new result list ...
}
```

Comment: You are #18 to misspell my name on SO. Congratulations. ;)